# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING & sublime

Tags: php, mamp, lamp, sublimetext3

Trying sublime3 (unregistered demo) today and really liking the workflow much better then dreamweaver but keep getting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING errors on my production LAMP server, but not my local MAMP testing server (using Filezilla for SFTP to lamp server)

I deleted everything in both of these test files, retyping(not copy and pasting) into each file only this... (using sublime)

UnitTest.php

```
<?php 
require_once ('dbentity.class.php');
?>
```

dbentity.class.php

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

or 
    
im getting the T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error

but if dbentity.class.php is

```
hello
```

(no php tags) I do get the result of "hello" being printed into the browser.

This is totally stumping me
I've checked the character encoding(UTF-8) and chmod (644) so that doesn't seem to be the problem. I've been developing in dreamweaver for about 2 years and haven't run into this problem, my best guess is that sublime is creating gremlins, but I know lots of PHP developers that use sublime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you should check besides encoding and chmod is line endings, I never stumbled upon a problem with them, but I know some people who have.

In Sublime go to `View` -> `Line endings` and set them to `Unix`.

I have always set them to Unix and never had any problems with any language, with any language interpreter/compiler and OS.

Comment: ok, figured it out, the reason 'hello' worked and the others didn't, its because it was just 1 line, so there were no line endings! the entire problem was my sublime was set to Mac OS 9 line endings ...

Comment: @Philippe but does it work with Unix? If it does I highly advise you to keep it set to unix as it's more universal

Comment: yes, unix line-endings works great (thats why I accepted your answer)